# Cannot find duplicates properly while comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, compare

I have two `Array` of issues. I must compare in order to create only when necessary, otherwise update.

This my the code I have:

```js
const issueList = [
  "Ajout de google analytics",
  "Déployement en continue dev",
  "Déployement en continue préproduction",
  "Déployement en continue production",
  "Déployment ipa automatique sur app store",
  "Déployment apk automatique sur play store"
];

const existingIssueList = [
  "Déployement en continue production",
  "Déployement en continue préproduction",
  "List swipe web"
];

for (let i = 0; i < issueList.length; i += 1) {
  let issueFound = null;
  for (let j = 0; j < existingIssueList.length; j += 1) {
    if (issueList[i] === existingIssueList[j]) {
      issueFound = existingIssueList[j];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // If issue was found, we do not need to create theissue
  let issue;
  if (issueFound) {
    issue = updateIssue({
      issue: issueFound,
    });
    console.log(`issue has been updated`);
  } else {
    issue = createIssue({
      issue: issueList[i],
    });
    console.log(`issue has been created`);
  }
}

function updateIssue(){}
function createIssue(){}
```

I expect to find the duplicated values and updates them, where am I failing ?

Comment: what should happen? please add the wanted result.

Comment: If you have to look up strings in a long array very often, use a `Set` instead as it has fast lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be very complex.Please check if you can use the below logic:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < issueList.length; i += 1) {
       if(existingIssueList.indexOf(issueList[i]) > -1) {
          //Issue already exists
       }else {
         //Create Issue 
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have added [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for readability reasons. After logged which issue is created/updated it looks like your code works:

```js
const issueList = [
  "Requetes de création de table commerçant",
  "Déployment apk automatique sur play store"
];

const existingIssueList = [
  "Déployment apk automatique sur play store",
  "Déployment ipa automatique sur app store",
  "Déployement en continue production",
  "Déployement en continue préproduction"
];

for (let i = 0; i < issueList.length; i += 1) {
  let issueFound = existingIssueList.includes(issueList[i]);
  
  // If issue was found, we do not need to create theissue
  let issue;
  if (issueFound) {
    issue = updateIssue({
      issue: issueFound,
    });
    console.log(`issue has been updated: ` + issueList[i]);
  } else {
    issue = createIssue({
      issue: issueList[i],
    });
    console.log(`issue has been created: ` + issueList[i]);
  }
}

function updateIssue(){}
function createIssue(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

lodash might help, something like

```
_.filter(issueList, (val, i, iteratee) => _.includes(iteratee, val, i + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const issueList = [
  "Déployement en continue dev",
  "Déployement en continue préproduction",
  "Déployement en continue production",
  "Déployment ipa automatique sur app store",
  "Déployment apk automatique sur play store"
];

const existingIssueList = [
  "Déployment apk automatique sur play store",
  "Déployment ipa automatique sur app store"
];

let issueFoundIndex = issueList.forEach(issue => {
    const existingIssueListIndex = existingIssueList.findIndex(x => x === issue);

    if(existingIssueListIndex !== -1){
      console.log('Found issue:' + existingIssueList[existingIssueListIndex]);
    }        

    const mutatedIssue = existingIssueListIndex !== -1
      ? updateIssue(existingIssueList[existingIssueListIndex])
      : createIssue(issue);
    console.log(mutatedIssue);
});

function updateIssue(issue){ return issue; }
function createIssue(issue){ return issue; }
```